# Como guardar MULTISURFACES en PostGis?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Tengo una tabla que guardar ciertas geometrias en una columna llamada geom de tipo de dato geometry, todas las geometrias son guardadas cuando esta tiene el siguiente valor

```
MULTIPOLYGON (((4790589.3686 2734106.8824,4790587.9476 2734098.7071,4790580.3633 2734100.0254,4790581.7842 2734108.2007,4790589.3686 2734106.8824)))
```

postgis me acepta insertar registros con valores similares al enterior pero el problema esta cuando uno de mis registros presenta el siguiente valor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
MULTISURFACE (CURVEPOLYGON (COMPOUNDCURVE ((4790297.991 2734133.0525,4790295.5512 2734126.1743,4790295.0845 2734126.3533,4790287.9907 2734129.0753,4790287.3312 2734129.3093,4790288.033 2734131.288,4790288.6926 2734131.054,4790288.7594 2734131.2425),CIRCULARSTRING (4790288.7594 2734131.2425,4790288.38388418 2734131.64106421,4790288.4889 2734132.1785),CIRCULARSTRING (4790288.4889 2734132.1785,4790288.69972776 2734132.34811985,4790288.9637 2734132.4076),CIRCULARSTRING (4790288.9637 2734132.4076,4790289.06354657 2734132.39860172,4790289.1605 2734132.3731),(4790289.1605 2734132.3731,4790289.2274 2734132.5616,4790288.0025 2734132.9961,4790289.2057 2734136.3881,4790290.4306 2734135.9536,4790297.5243 2734133.2316,4790297.991 2734133.0525))))
```

al intentar agregar el valor a mi columna de tipo de dato gometry me arroja el error que pueden ver en la imagen anterior

he intantado cambiar el tipo de dato de geometry a geometry_dump para comprobrar si este la soluciona pero me genera el mismo error

a que se debe este error?

Comment: El error que estás viendo se debe a que la geometría que estás intentando insertar en la columna de tipo geometry no tiene un formato válido. La geometría que has proporcionado es una MULTISURFACE (superficie múltiple) que contiene una CURVEPOLYGON (polígono curvo) con un COMPOUNDCURVE (curva compuesta) y tres CIRCULARSTRINGs (cadenas circulares). PostGIS no soporta el tipo de geometría MULTISURFACE, por lo que el intento de insertar esta geometría en una columna de tipo geometry falla. En su lugar, deberías utilizar un tipo de geometría que soporte este tipo de geometría, como geometry_dump.

Comment: Sabes de alguna herramienta que me pueda ayudar a validar el formato del MULTISURFACE que intento insertar?

Comment: espero no haber sido tan extenso

Comment: Tengo una duda, ese campo de tipo GEOMETRY(MULTISURFACE) es el mismo campo geometry_dump o te refieres a otro tipo de campo?